# Domain name not showing on Google search (suggestions list)

Tags: google, domains, search

Please help with this confusing issue...

My domain name not showing on Google search (suggestion list).
When I type the domain name (yoxtel) on Google search bar, it does not show on the suggestion list. But other similar domains such as foxtel showns.

It show search results only when I type the domain name and hit enter.
I feel that whatever is the problem is preventing the website from ranking.

The Domain/website is indexed and has been running for over 2 years.
No error on Google webmastertool for this site.

See attached image.[image: domain google search]

Any help to point me to the right direction to resolve  this will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The search query box suggestion comes from a variety of places all working together.

One is the terms index. Since neither yoxtel or foxtel are known terms, this does not apply to you.

Another is the semantic analysis of the search query log. Here, any term would have to have a significant search history to show up in the search query box as a suggestion. This may apply to you in that there may be a significant amount of search for Foxtel and not for Yoxtel.

Last, branding and other significant similar terms. These terms are for brands and product names, models, and so on that not only show up in the search query log, but Google also recognizes them as a brand. In this case, the term may be coming from the knowledge-graph or a similar knowledge base specific to brands and brand terms.

It appears that Foxtel is a very strong brand while Yoxtel is not. I count 46 branding signals. Not all of them need to exist of course, however, as many branding signals should exist for any company. The one thing that stands out is that Foxtel is within the knowledge-graph. It is likely that Foxtel has an entry in Wikipedia. It is for at least this reason why Foxtel appears as a suggestion. It is strong brand name.

Comment: closetnoc, Thank you for your explanations. What I am getting is that nothing is wrong with the site but branding issue. My concern is that all other unknown sites are showing up, still not sure what to do technically or otherwise to change that.

Comment: @DChrisly Yes. You are right. The second half of this answer should get you started. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85689/why-is-the-string-ruby-shoo-appearing-in-the-page-title-of-a-lot-of-our-goog/85722#85722 Also brand popularity is a major part of this. Search queries must also contain your brand name. You can also add an Wikipedia page for your brand. This is a huge signal for Google.