# Why is the string "- Ruby Shoo" appearing in the page title of a lot of our google search results?

Tags: seo, local-seo

In the Google Search Results Automatically adding "Ruby Shoo" text. While it is not adding in Meta Title, Description, H1 or Keywords.

Please Check and help me to solve this issue.

Simply search in google "site:http://www.shoerepublik.ie/" and check below image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you have this as the title of the homepage -

Buy Shoes Online | Rieker | Gabor | Ruby Shoo | Dubarry | Shoe Republik™ Ireland

and "Ruby Shoo" text is repeated 25 times on your homepage while Shoe Republik is repeated only 5 times.

Google algorithm is picking up the most important part of the home page title thinking it's your **brand name**.

Comment: While I appreciate what you have said here, it is technically incorrect. You are, however, pointing out a couple of problems of which I found quite a few.

Comment: I do not fully understand your comment. Google does pickup brand name and put them at start or end of the title all the time. And here, google is picking up 'Ruby Shoo' as their brand name.

Comment: And that is the point. Ruby Shoo does not appear to me to be their brand but a brand they carry. I will look again.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with this site.

The correct technical answer is that your title tag on these particular pages is too short. In the case where the title tag is too short, Google may select another content segment for the title or chose to brand the SERP link. In this case, Google is branding your SERP link with what it thinks is your brand. Obviously it is not your brand. You need to fix this.

*Solving the title tag issue with opportunity.*

To begin, make the title tags for these pages longer and more descriptive. This is an opportunity to have these pages rank better for your brand. It should be between 45-50 character (actual measure is 512 pixels). Keep in mind that wider characters such as W, D, G, M, etc. will eat into the number of characters you can use and why the recommendation is for 45-50 characters. Using this technique, you can control the branding of the pages yourself.

You can experiment and tune your title tags for these pages. Use Fetch as Google option in Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools) to test the results. When you are satisfied with the results, you can use the Submit to Index option. This is not immediate and can take a couple of days to actually appear in the SERPs.

*Solving the branding problem.*

There are 46 branding signals by my last count. You do not need to worry about all of them. However, you need to at least pay attention to some key signals.

The first is to use schema.org mark-up. You can use http://schema.org/LocalBusiness for your address. Make sure that you are using your *company name* in this mark-up and not just the address, phone number, etc. You already have your company name and address at the bottom of the page. This is very good! Use mark-up to help search engines understand who you are. You should also use mark-up on your *contact us* with the company name. I would also suggest also placing the same mark-up on your about us page.

To make things clear, you should also use http://schema.org/Product and http://schema.org/Offer where they apply. This will help generate search traffic.

Another powerful tool to help Google understand your brand is to create a Google+ for business page for your brand.

Also, pay attention to the various web based business listing and manage these accounts. This is another opportunity tune your brand name that search engines will use to understand who you are.

Google, for example, pays heavy attention to any Google+ listing and web based business listings for branding clues.

*Other important information.*

Your home page title is too long and contains brand names that are not yours separated by the pipe character. You are using too many pipes and keywords. It will, and already has in part, gotten you into trouble.

For pipes in any title, I do not recommend going over 2. Pipes are important in that you can use them to separate important clusters of terms that Google, at least, will pay attention to. Too many pipes will signal that your title is keyword loaded. Something you want to avoid. Your pages will drop in the SERPs and possibly be de-listed as a result.

Your home page should be about your company. You will want to use your brand on this page and drop the other brand names. It is not always important to make a home page rank especially for e-commerce sites. The pages that are important to rank are those pages that sell product. While you do have products on your home page, it is better to have product brand pages that rank for the individual brand names that you carry. Do not confuse search engines with these brand names on your home page. You can also use the product brand on the individual product pages.

Your about us page does not have a title. It may not be the only one. You will always want to make sure you use a title tag on all pages, otherwise, you are leaving it up to search engines to make one up. You may not like what they choose. Remember that you want to actively manage your title tags for all pages. Semantically speaking, the title tag is the single most important HTML DOM element you can use to influence search. Make sure you do not miss this opportunity.

How Google has confused your brand is unclear. Search engines expect your home page to be about you. In this, Google may have assumed that Ruby Shoe was your brand resulting in shoe phoo. Clearly this is a major flaw in Googles branding algorithm. You can avoid this and improve your site quickly, however, influencing the SERPs can take months. For key pages you can use the Fetch as Google option, but not too much. You should be okay following these simple steps.