# My domain name is not in search but few other pages are in search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains

This is really weird but its happening. The domain is about 6 months old and was built with wordpress. It was hacked (a lot of pages were appending after domain name in chinese language etc. I could see using site:domain.com) but I am not getting any clicks from those hacked pages anymore.

Now it is in different hosting and built from scratch, not using wordpress anymore. I submitted new site to google and it shows indexed. One of the page (domain.com/certification) is even appearing in google search on page 1/2.

However when I type domain name 'domain' in search. Its not there. It shows whois domain, domain.sg or some other extension but not domain.com. Seems like my domain does not exist at all?

Does deleting domain from search console and starting from scratch helps? Does verifying domain ownership with different methods help?

Even brand new site shows up after a week or two but something is going on here. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Just for sake of clarity, do you mean you have a domain `example.com` and when you type just `example` (not `"example.com"`) in Google Search, your site isn't appearing? If so, see [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88557/brand-name-as-keyword-for-a-brand-com-site-how-to-make-it-appear-in-search) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85536/domain-name-not-showing-on-google-search-suggestions-list?rq=1) related question.

Comment: ya example.com Weather i type example or example.com its not there.

Comment: It takes quite a while to build brand name recognition in Google, see the questions I linked to in my comment above.

Comment: I have deployed 5/6 sites before. They dont take more than a week or two. I can type the full domain name like example.com and it shows up. But not this time... domain is not new its like 6 months old. one of the page is already on second page of google search like domain.com/certification

Comment: When you say `type the full domain name like example.com and it shows up` modern browsers will go to that site if you do that, so do you mean in quotes like `"example.com"`? That's quite a bit different from just `example` alone, which is considered a "brand" or business name. Google returns SERP based on what it finds on sites, and if whatever `example` is isn't well-known or associated to your site by Google, then you'll need to be sure to use it in your site quite a bit and try to build authority for it (e.g., get links to it from other relevant sites).

Comment: After reading the above link, I realized that we might need to focus on short form of site ABC from Alpha & Beta Company. Because thats our brand name(imaginary) Alpha & Beta Company and our domain is abc.com when i type abc or abc.com its not there but when i type Alpha & Beta Company it shows up.

Comment: Yes, acronyms have no meaning to Google until you build brand-name recognition for them. See the first link above - we have a lot more related questions here too (search on "brand").